# tensorboardにおけるグラフ表示について

Tags: python, tensorflow

こんにちは。pythonでtensorflowを独学している者です。内容は画像認識のための深層学習です。
その過程でtensorboadを利用するのですが、tensorflowでの学習過程をグラフに可視化する際、「訓練用データに対する精度・誤差」だけでなく「テスト用データに対する精度・誤差」もグラフに反映させられないかと思い、質問致しました。
浅学なもので恐縮ですがご解答いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

train/
validation/

それぞれのディレクトリの中にログデータが入っているみたいな状況でしょうか

```
./logs/
├ train/
└ validation/
```

という構成にして，

```
tensorboard --logdir=./logs
```

と打ち込むと二つのグラフが同時に描画されるかと思います．